# Information logging is logging type instead of value

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2, nemlogin

I'm implementing NemLog-in3 / OIOSAML 3 authentication in my .NET Core web application. With great success so far. I have a question though, about the logging requirements for OIOSAML integrations. There is a list of things that must be validated and logged for all assertions. For example assertion ID, certificate validation results, user session id etc.

I have implemented a new event listener for the static EventSource logger from Microsoft, since i can see that you're emitting log events to that logger, in your NuGet package.

See ing the log messages, made me wonder if there is a bug or if it's intensional to log the type instead of the actual value? See picture below.

[image: Logging messages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug, it is not intended to log the type information.

The default logging in the library do not support the OIOSAML logging requirements at all. Connected to [OIOSAML logging requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69189392/oiosaml-logging-requirements/69223330)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, i will look into it. Do you plan on fixing the bug in a future release?

Comment: I'm using version 4.7.0 by the way.

Comment: Please add the bug as an issue on https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 and I'll look into it. You are also welcome to create a pull request if you know of a solution.